# VHDL how to check for coincidence during set time period

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to implement coincidence check on signals which can come during preset timeframe into an FPGA using VHDL, and i fear I am probably trying to invent something very basic which was done many times already...

Desired module funcionality:

Remember there was a signal on one of inputs, and after preset time period treat these remembered signals as synchronous and send them further into the circuit.

Example: Listen on 2 input ports (A,B), incase at least one 10 ns long signal is sensed on an input,  store it, and in 500ns periods send stored signals further and reset.

So far i came up with this:

Storing inputs:

```
memory_A <= A when ( memory_A = '0' );
memory_B <= B when ( memory_B = '0' );
```

Now i need to send them further and reset. I have a module which gives me 10ns long pulses in 500ns intervals, so i will use its output to clock my process:

```
process(pulse)
  begin
     if(pulse'event and pulse='1') then
                                          -- generate output signals
        modified_output_A <= memory_A
        modified_output_B <= memory_B
                                          -- reset the storage
        memory_A <= '0'
        memory_B <= '0'
     end if;

  end process;
```

I will wrap this up into a module with

inputs:   A,B and pulse
 outputs: modified_A, modified_B.

Now i am getting synchronous A,B signals i can apply logic on ( check for coincidence etc. ).

My questions are:

- Is this going to work?
- Is this a good way to do it, are there any downsides or catches i might not be seeing?
- If this is not a good way to do this, how should this be done?

Thans for all feedback/help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you have multiple drivers on *memory_A* and *memory_B*.
You should only assign them in the process.

Also I'm not sure if it's good design practice to use **signal**'*event* on non-clock signals.
Could depend on your synthesis-tool. I would use a clocked process and get the rising-edge by a shift-register.
Or should they not be clocked register outputs?

Also I am missing a reset and a clock signal ;)